# Bounding absolute value of product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions such that
$$\int_0^\infty g(y)dy=0$$
and
$$|f(y)|\leq 1$$
Then how can I bound the absolute value of the product
$$\bigg|\int_0^\infty f(\xi)g(y)dy \bigg|$$
where $\xi \in [0,y]$.

I tried
$$\bigg|\int_0^\infty f(\xi)g(y)dy \bigg| \leq \int_0^\infty \bigg|  f(\xi)g(y)dy \bigg| \leq \int_0^\infty |g(y)|dy$$
But I don't think this will give a bound. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: No. The supremum of $|\int_0^\infty f(\xi)g(y)dy|$ over all such $f$ is exactly $\int |g(y)|dy$

Comment: I think a bound is impossible. Consider $$g(y) = e^{-\lfloor y\rfloor}\sin 2\pi y $$ and $$f(y) = (-1)^{\lfloor 2y \rfloor}$$

Comment: If you mean $\xi$ is independent of $y$, then $\left|\int _0^\infty f(\xi)g(y)\mathrm d y \right|= |f(\xi)| \cdot \left|\int_0^\infty g(y)\mathrm dy\right| = 0$.